# Trying to replace strings in an HTML document and adding extra characters

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace

What I'm trying to do is open up a file and search for "searchText". I want to replace all the instances of it in the file with a new link, which is actually just the filename with an achor link so instead of opening up javascript it just goes to another point in the page.

So far what I have is this:

```
private void writeNotes(){
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();

        string fileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
        string searchText = "<a class=\"x-fn\" href=\"javascript:void(0);\">";
        string replaceText = "<a class=\"x-fn\" href=\"" + fileName + "#fn" + "\">";

        content = Regex.Replace(content, searchText, replaceText);

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Close();
```

However, after writing and closing... I open up the file and no changes were made. Besides that, what I want to do is add a number that counts up after "#fn" for every instance of replacement. So, basically, for every time I replace the javascript link with another, I want it to be:

```
<a class="x-fn" href="fileName#fn1">
```

And then when I replace the second instance of javascript, it reads

```
<a class="x-fn" href="fileName#fn2">
```

and so on...

I imagine I would have to count the instances of how many times the javascript appears, replace it, and use a for loop to iterate throughout all of the new links and add the #fn(n) at the end?

Comment: You know you can use HtmlAgilityPack for HTML editing as well, right?

Comment: Why are you using regex? A simple string replace will do.. especially since your search string is NOT a regex!!!

Comment: use the debugger.  Maybe your regex isn't finding a match.  I'd also suggest using string replace as banging said.  Don't have to worry about special regex symbols that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have metacharacters (in this case, the open and close paren in "void(0)").  Instead of representing literal open and close parens, that is creating a regular expression group, which is causing your match to fail.  If you escape the parens with a backslash, it will work as expected.

However, since you're just matching a string literal, you don't need to use regular expressions at all; it'll be faster to use `string.Replace`.

As for the second part of your question, that's a little trickier.  There's no easy way to do it that I know of, so the best approach is to look for your search text in the input, and then build up a `StringBuilder` as you go along, incrementing a count variable.  In the following example, the word "the" is replaced by "(0)" and "(1)" for simplicity's sake, but you can adapt it to your problem easily enough.

```
var content = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
var searchText = "the";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var idx = -1; // will hold the index of our search text
var uncopiedIdx = 0; // the start index of what hasn't been copied yet
var replacementCount = 0;
while( (idx = content.IndexOf( searchText, idx+1 )) != -1 ) {
    // copy everything leading up to our search text
    sb.Append( content.Substring( uncopiedIdx, idx-uncopiedIdx ) );
    // copy the replacement text, with the replacement count
    var replacement = "(" + replacementCount++ + ")";
    sb.Append( replacement );
    // skip over the search text
    uncopiedIdx = idx + searchText.Length;
}
// copy everything after the last match
sb.Append( content.Substring( uncopiedIdx ) );
```

Comment: You can also use `Regex.Escape` to ensure that a string is treated as all literals in a regular expression.

Comment: Alright, I'm removed Regex and instead just used string.Replace. However, after I run it, the changes still aren't being made. Am I saving it incorrectly by chance? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're opening the file with `SafeFileName`, which does not include the path, but then you're saving it with `FileName`, which does include the path.  So you may be saving the file in a different location from which you're opening it....

Comment: Hey buddy, it's working fine now! But still, do you have any idea how to add a number at the end of each string that is replaced that counts up for every instance?

Comment: Glad to hear it's working.  Your second problem, though, is going to require a little more work.  Let me think about it and update my answer.

Comment: Great, I was thinking, should I search for all the positions of "#fn" and then add them to a list? Then, in a for loop, add Count++ so it adds the number to the list of positions? Keep in mind that I don't entirely know how to do this, just thinking out loud, haha.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the second part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MatchEvaluator which should do it all at once.
Something like this -

C#

```
string content = 
 @"
     <a class=""x-fn"" href=""javascript:void(0);"">
     <a class='x-fn' href = ""javascript:void(0); "">
     <a href='javascript:void(0);' class=x-fn >
     <a class=""x-fn"" href=javascript:void(0); >
     <a 'hello' href=javascript:void(0); world class=x-fn >
  ";
 string fileName = "FILE";

 Regex jsRx =  new Regex(
  @"
     <a 
         (?=\s) 
         (?= 
             (?: [^>""']|""[^""]*""|'[^']*')*? (?<=\s)
             class \s*=
             (?:
                 (?> \s* (['""])  \s* x-fn  \s* \1 )         # (1) quote
               | (?> (?!\s*['""]) \s* x-fn  (?=\s|>)   )
             )
         )
         (?= 
             ( (?: [^>""']|""[^""]*""|'[^']*')*? ) (?<=\s)       # (2) - before 'href'
             href \s*=
             (?:
                 (?> \s* (['""])  \s* javascript:void\(0\); \s* \3   )   # (3) quote
               | (?> (?!\s*['""]) \s* javascript:void\(0\); (?=\s|>) )
             )
             ( (?> (?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^>]?)+ ) )                  # (4) - after 'href'
         )
         (?> \s+ (?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+ 
     >        
         ) (?<! /> )
  ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline);

 int counter = 0;
 string contentNew = jsRx.Replace( content, delegate(Match match)
 {
     return "<a" + match.Groups[2] + "href=\"" + fileName + "#fn" + (counter++) + "\"" + match.Groups[4] + ">";
 });

 Console.WriteLine( contentNew );
```

Output

```
<a class="x-fn" href="FILE#fn0">
<a class='x-fn' href="FILE#fn1">
<a href="FILE#fn2" class=x-fn >
<a class="x-fn" href="FILE#fn3" >
<a 'hello' href="FILE#fn4" world class=x-fn >
```

Comment: Your welcome! Its a solution thats taken a year to perfect. No longer an idea.